# What are the differences between `test`, `include`, `resource` attributes in webpack modules rules configuration?

Tags: webpack, webpack-config

In `webpack.config.js` to determine module we can use 3 different attributes:

```
...
module:{
    rules: [
        {
            test: ... // the first one, commonly used in most example we can found on internet
            include: ... // the second one
            resource: ... // the third one
            use: ['style-loader','css-loader'],
        },
        ...
    ],  
    ...
}
```

Docs are not explanatory about them:

> [**Rule.test**](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruletest) 
>  Include all modules that pass test assertion. If you supply a `Rule.test` option, you cannot also supply a `Rule.resource`. See `Rule.resource` and `Condition.test` for details.

> [**Rule.include**](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleinclude) 
>  Include all modules matching any of these conditions. If you supply a `Rule.include` option, you cannot also supply a `Rule.resource`. See `Rule.resource` and `Condition.include` for details.

> [**Rule.resource**](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#ruleresource) 
> A `Condition` matched with the resource. See details in `Rule` conditions.

Each of them are `Condition` type.  Some of them are mutually exclusive.  But what is the purpose of each? When we should use each?

If there will be only `test` everything would be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the complete history of Webpack, but I believe `Rule.resource` is a legacy option that is being phased out, since almost no one is using it.

With `Rule.resource` you can have sub-conditions, which would otherwise be complicated to write using a single RegExp:

```js
{
  resource: {
    and: [
      /\.js$/,
      /src\/directory/,
    ],
    not: /node_modules/
  }
}
```

That looks a lot like how you would use the `Rule.test`, `Rule.include`, and `Rule.exclude` options, which used to be called shortcut options, but they are now the main ones.

Nowadays the way you are meant to use them is to match the file extension with `Rule.test` and if you need to list specific directories or specific files you should use `Rule.include` or `Rule.exclude`.

This convention makes config easy to read and easy to reuse across projects.

`Rule.test` and `Rule.include` actually work the same way, you could even merge them into a single condition, but at that point you might as well go back to `Rule.resource`.

Currently `Rule.resource` works the same as `Rule.test`, so there is no point in using both, that is probably why they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: Your answer make sense. I will wait couple week, if no one have any comments I will accept your answer.